# How do I iterate through two dataframes of different sizes?

Tags: python, pandas

Specifically I want to iterate through two dataframes, one being large and one being small.

Ultimately, I would like to compare values within a certain column.

I tried creating a nested for loop; the outer loop iterating through the large dataframe and the inner loop iterating through the small dataframe however I am having difficulties.

I'm looking for a way to identify that the "name" and "value" in my large dataframe that matches my small dataframe.

Background info: I am using the panda library.

Large dataframe:

[image]

Small dataframe:

```
Name     Value
SF       12.84
TH      -49.45
```

Comment: Can you post example where you are having problem?

Comment: Hello I have posted the two dataframes!

Comment: @harro what you need as a output

Comment: Do you want to get the common value from 2 dataframe?

Comment: Hi Zaynul and Sam, I would like to create another column (sort of like a flag column) within my large dataframe that will place a 1 if those conditions of: same "name" and "value" match . If does not match then place a 0.

Comment: If that is hard to do, maybe just a way to identify that the common value matches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is to iterate through one, or especially more, `DataFrame`s, then explicit `for` loops is usually the wrong move. In this case, because you're trying to

> identify that the "name" and "value" in my large dataframe that matches my small dataframe,

the operation that you're looking for is either `pd.merge` or `pd.DataFrame.join` which do the comparisons "under the hood" and return matching information. So, say you have the 2 `DataFrame`s and they're called `large` and `small`. Then

```
import pandas as pd
new_large = pd.merge(left=large,
                     right=small,
                     how='left',
                     on=('Name', 'Value'),
                     indicator=True)

new_large._merge = new_large._merge.apply(lambda x: 1 if x=='both' else 0)
```

By doing a left join between `large` and `small` (`how='left'`), `pd.merge` returns the rows in `large` that contain a match in `small` on the `('Name', 'Value')` tuple. Then, most of the heavy lifting is done by the `indicator` keyword that, quoting the `pd.merge` version 0.25.0 docs:

> If True, adds a column to output DataFrame called "_merge" with
>       information on the source of each row.
>       Information column is Categorical-type and takes on a value of "left_only"
>       for observations whose merge key only appears in 'left' DataFrame,
>       "right_only" for observations whose merge key only appears in 'right'
>       DataFrame, and "both" if the observation's merge key is found in both.

So, `new_large` is the original `large` `DataFrame` with a new column called `_merge` the entries of which correspond to the rows of `large` that matched `small` just on `Name` (by the value `'left_only'`) and the rows that matched on `Name` as well as `Value`; the latter having the value `both`. The last step is changing `both` and `left_only` to `1` and `0`, as you specified.

Now, the left join returned what it did because both of the `Name` values in the small `DataFrame` were present in the `large` `DataFrame` so the left-join of `large` and `small` returned the whole `large` `DataFrame`. When this is not the case, there will be `pd.NaN` values resulting from `pd.merge` and you'll have to employ a few more tricks to get the nice Boolean (integer) column to show what matched and what didn't. HTH.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!!